# How to get the href value of a link with bs4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need help where I can extract all the matches from 2020/2021's URLs from this [website][1] and scrape them.

I am sending a request to this [link](https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/ipl-2020-21-1210595/match-results).

The section of the HTML that I want to retrieve is this part:

```
Here's the code that I am using:

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    import urllib.parse
    website = 'https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/ipl-2020-21-1210595/match-results'
    response = requests.get(website)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
    match_result = soup.find_all('a',{'class':'match-info-link-FIXTURES'});
    soup.get('href')
    url_part_1 = 'https://www.espncricinfo.com/'
    url_part_2 = []
    for item in match_result:
        url_part_2.append(item.get('href'))
    url_joined = []
    for link_2 in url_part_2:
        url_joined.append(urllib.parse.urljoin(url_part_1,link_2))
    first_link = url_joined[0]
    match_url = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'link-container border-bottom'});
    soup.get('href')
    url_part_3 = 'https://www.espncricinfo.com/'
    url_part_4 = []
    for item in match_result:
        url_part_4.append(item.get('href'))
    
    print(url_part_4)

  [1]: https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/ipl-2020-21-1210595/match-results
```

Comment: I think I saw exactly the same problem before in other question. Did you create again the same question (and delete previous)?  I think you still have the same problem - you  didn't explain what special is in links which you want to get. How we have to recognize which links you want and which to skip. You also didn't explain what is wrong with your code. Don't expect that we will run it to see problem. And we can't read in your mind.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you get in variables. And first check what you get in `response.content` - maybe you get different HTML then you see in browser. Servers may send different HTML for different browsers and devices (phone, table, notebook). You could also get HTML with warning message for bots/spamers/hackers or with Captcha. But you can't know if you don't check `response.content`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second `item.find_all('a',{'class':'match-info-link-FIXTURES'}):` call below `for item in match_result:` since you already have the tags with the hrefs.

You can get the href with `item.get('href')`.

You can do:

```
url_part_1 = 'https://www.espncricinfo.com/'
url_part_2 = []
for item in match_result:
    url_part_2.append(item.get('href'))
```

The result will look something like:

```
['/series/ipl-2020-21-1210595/delhi-capitals-vs-mumbai-indians-final-1237181/full-scorecard',
 '/series/ipl-2020-21-1210595/delhi-capitals-vs-sunrisers-hyderabad-qualifier-2-1237180/full-scorecard',
 '/series/ipl-2020-21-1210595/royal-challengers-bangalore-vs-sunrisers-hyderabad-eliminator-1237178/full-scorecard',
 '/series/ipl-2020-21-1210595/delhi-capitals-vs-mumbai-indians-qualifier-1-1237177/full-scorecard',
 '/series/ipl-2020-21-1210595/sunrisers-hyderabad-vs-mumbai-indians-56th-match-1216495/full-scorecard',
...
]
```

Comment: Brother i already get scorecard link i need ball by ball commentary link

Answer (score 0):

From official [doc's](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)
:

> It’s very useful to search for a tag that has a certain CSS class, but the name of the CSS attribute, `“class”`, is a reserved word in Python. Using `class` as a keyword argument will give you a syntax error. As of Beautiful Soup 4.1.2, you can search by CSS class using the keyword argument `class_`.

Try

```
soup.find_all("a", class_="match-info-link-FIXTURES")
```